# Charts-ios in OC : delegate can't be called

Tags: ios-charts

I had added the ChartViewDelegate to my program and set the 'chartView.delegate = slef',but the delegate method still can not be called.What should I do?

Xcode 8.2
Charts 3.0.1
OC

Comment: I feel `chartView` object might be null or nil as result delegate won't be getting a set which could result in such behavior, I am using the ios-charts library and we are able to call the delegate properly.

Comment: thank you . finally it had been eliminated. I found that the delegate of chartView was assigned a wrong target.